# Design and Layout for PrintDocument

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008

I may sound silly but was wondering if there is any way I can design the print layout i.e font-size, font-color, spacing, margins and coordinates for the string/text being printed and generate the code as .graphics.drawstring(....)

Comment: There are many, many report generators that specialize in doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like that with meta files.  In a metafile, you can draw into a metafile, and then plot it in one command.

More information can be found at:

- [Drawing on an in-memory metafile in C#](http://nicholas.piasecki.name/blog/2009/06/drawing-o-an-in-memory-metafile-in-c-sharp/)
- [Working with Metafile Images in .Net](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/177394/Working-with-Metafile-Images-in-Net)